# Inherited IBOutlets vanish after changing layout to constraints

Tags: iboutlet, xcode5

**Scenario:**

A Child UIViewController inherits some IBOutlets from its parent UIViewController (which doesn't have its own XIB). 
Hence we have child+parent IBOutlets linked to the child's Interface Builder (XIB).

Originally, within a frame-based layout paradigm, I could link BOTH sets of IBOutlets from the child UIViewController's XIB as a single list.

However, *apparently,* after converting to a constraint-based layout, the XIB can't see the inherited IBOutlets; only the local (File's Owner) IBOutlets can still be seen.

That is, the IB complains that the File's Owner (the child UIViewController) **does not have** the inherited IBOutlets.

**Question:**
1) Is it proper to inherit IBOutlets from a parent UIViewController and if true, how do I fix this?
... or, **must all IBOutlets** be declared (as local IBOutlets) in the de-facto "File's Owner" (which in this case is the child UIViewController)?

Answer (score 0):

The IB's "File's Owner" was linked to a vestigial class that had been renamed.

Hence the loss of IBOutlets.